# Ajax CalendarExtender giving the wrong format asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, datetime, calendarextender

I'm using an Ajax CalendarExtender attached to a textbox  in my page.
I am able to get the date at the correct format when the textbox to which it is attached is Null at the begining .
But then  i load date values from my database, and this time i want to get the new date selected in the calendar to update it in my database.
for this purpose i use a javascript function to retrieve this date and store it in a hiddenfield so i could use it in code behind later.
problem is the dates retrieved are correct, but in adifferent format the calendar format .

here is my aspx code :

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="124px" ReadOnly=false
                    ontextchanged="TextBox2_TextChanged"  OnChange="SetHiddenVariable1()" ></asp:TextBox>

                <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="TextBox2_CalendarExtender" BehaviorID="TextBox2_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
                    TargetControlID="TextBox2" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" Enabled="True"  >
                </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
```

and here is the javascript used:

```
function SetHiddenVariable1() {
    var hiddenControl1 = '<%= HiddenField_date_debut.ClientID %>';
    document.getElementById(hiddenControl1).value = $find("TextBox2_CalendarExtender").get_selectedDate();
}
```

the result in HiddenField_dateçdebut:

> when i select **30/07/2013** in the calendar i get **Tue Jul 30 2013 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été))** in the hidden field

How Can I store this value in the hiddenfield in the correct format? 
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to try and fix just the formatting do the following by adding `.format("dd/MM/yyyy")` at the end

```
 $find("TextBox2_CalendarExtender").get_selectedDate().format("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: Awesome! Can you please mark my answer with the green mark? Much appreciated.

Comment: Done. i was just waiting for the necessary 15min wait-time to pass to mark the answer.